# Deduct from stock if someone picks a specific property while adding an item to the card in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

there's 3 types of items in our clothing web store (**magento 2.3.1**),
there are:

- A) Bottoms
- B) Tops
- C) Sets (both a bottom and a top)

All of which come in different colors and sizes.

I'd love to know how set our products up, so far I thought of 2 scenarios:

- **Scenario 1)**

Set the **bottoms** (A) and **tops** (B) as configurable products (add the color and size properties), and set the **sets** (C) as bundle products, then add A and B's as related products inside C.

That will allow the stock to be deducted when someone i.e only buys a top, so that the user can't buy the bundle if there are no more tops.

- **Scenario 2)**

Set the **sets** (C) as a configurable product (add the color and size properties), but also add an extra property, on which they can select wether they want to only buy the bottom, only the top, or both (sets).

I like that scenario more, but if I do that, I run the risk of someone purchasing a set, when i.e there's no top in our stock (because people bought more tops for example, and no bottoms).

What would be the right way to deal with that issue? Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your business model.

As I understand from what you wrote, you would like to sell tops and bottoms individually and also in sets.

Maybe the cleanest would be if you just create a bundle product for sets and allow people to not select either top or bottom.

Also with that, it would be okay if you show the individual products for bottoms and tops.